# Running install4j installer on Mac OS 10.7.4 with Oracle JRE1.7

Tags: macos, osx-lion, java, install4j, exe4j

I have a installer which is built with install4j 5.1.2. When i try to install it on Mac OS X 10.7.4. It complains saying

"No JVM could be found on you
 system.
 Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME
 to point to an installed JDK or JRE or download a JRE from 
 www.java.com"

Then i download just the JRE1.7_07 from Oracle and tried again, i got the same error. Where as if i install full JDK1.7_07, then everything works fine.

Additional Information:

1. If i use Apple JRE 1.6 installer works fine. But my app needs JRE 1.7.
2. I also defined environment variables for JAVA_HOME, EXE4J_JAVA_HOME when i installed JRE1.7, Still i saw the same error. I have a feeling that, install4J is not reading the JRE when JRE is installed.
3. If i install JDK, then the JRE is in the following location 
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/ 
   where as if i install only JRE, it is in the following location 
   /Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

I am not sure, if i am missing something. any pointers on how to resolve this particular issue is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got below email from install4j support.

Hi,

Thanks for your email. Indeed, 5.1.2 cannot find the JRE but only the JDK, since
the JRE was not released when OpenJDK support was implemented for install4j. This
is implemented in the current 5.1.3 build:

http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_windows_5_1_3.exe

http://download.ej-technologies.com/beta/install4j_windows-x64_5_1_3.exe

It will be released at the end of the month.

Kind regards,